# Get specific data from PHP in AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have this echo in php:

```
[Username=Admin&c_x=0&c_y=0&c_talk=NULL], [Username=Admin2&c_x=0&c_y=0&c_talk=Hello],
```

So I loaded this URL to my flash site, and I want to trace only the first username (Admin) and the first c_talk (Null).

How do I do this?

I tried:

```
ServerVars = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
trace(ServerVars.Username);
```

but it didn't worked correctly.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because that's not a valid string for URL variables.

The echoed string is trying to return a list of two groups of key value pairs. Grouped by [] brackets, which doesn't work. In general, there is no grouping possible. Instead of coming up with your own custom format, use an existing commonly used one like [json](http://json.org/). (or XML if you feel like) Those supported structured data as you require.

Return a json array of objects (PHP has built in methods for that I'm sure, so please **don't** assemble this as a string yourself)

```
[
    {
        "Username" : "Admin",
        "x" : 0,
        "y" : 0,
        "talk" : "" 
    },
    {
        "Username" : "Admin2",
        "x" : 0,
        "y" : 0,
        "talk" : "Hello"    
    }
]
```

Shove that into As3's [`JSON`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) class and work with the result.